# detection of remote Hangup on analog modem

Tags: c++, modem, at-command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hayes AT Commands: Detect Remote Hangup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253965/hayes-at-commands-detect-remote-hangup)

Im writting a c++ program to operate a analog modem. I'm not able to detect remote hangup. However i have been able to configure and make calls.

Is there any way to handle the remote hangup in modem which does not provide and response for remote hangup?

Comment: Did you take a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253965/hayes-at-commands-detect-remote-hangup] ?

Comment: Yes i have looked at it already. But my modem doesn't support '+++'  command mode.

Comment: Yes i have looked at it already. But my modem doesn't support '+++'  command mode. Im using multitech MT5656ZDX.