# C# Response from USB Modem/Call using AT Commands

Tags: c#, usb, at-command, modem

I am quite relatively new to AT Commands and would appreciate some help. I have a USB Modem which I am trying to use to perform a phone call using the following code snippet:

```
SerialPort SP = new SerialPort("COM3");
SP.BaudRate = 9600;
SP.Parity = Parity.None;
SP.DataBits = 8;
SP.StopBits = StopBits.One;
SP.RtsEnable = true;
SP.DtrEnable = true;
SP.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
SP.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
SP.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
SP.Open();
SP.Write("ATDT 123456;\r");

string response = SP.ReadExisting();

if (response.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Modem / Call connected");
}

SP.Close();
```

The phone call is being done if I specify my mobile number for example. I get the "OK" response. However I have the following situations that I would like to detect.

1. How to detect if a call was rejected (example from mobile I decline the call). How can I read if the call was rejected by user?
2. When dialing an unknown number, I still get the OK response, even if the number is invalid.
3. How to detect if the number being dialed is Busy (line is already in use)

Is this possible to be done using AT Commands?

Comment: What is an "unknown number"?  If you mean a wrong number, a modem can't know that.  If it's a valid number, it will dial it.  Any series of #'s is effectively a valid number.  Also, what does "decline the call" mean?  Is that just someone hanging up the phone?  Again, a modem can't know that means anything other than hanging up.  You will get a "BUSY" response if the # is busy.

Comment: Yes by "unknown number" I meant a wrong number. By "Decline a call" meaning the user hung up the phone. I basically want to track the line status once a call has been initiated. Therefore in theory I would assume that using AT Commands this is not achievable. What tool/technology could be used to get the line status (Wrong Number/Call Declined/Busy etc).

Comment: There's no "response" to a hang-up (or declined call) because it's not an AT command that is invoked from the modem-side (it's something that happens on the remote-side).  You can monitor connection status by trying to switch to command mode (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253965/hayes-at-commands-detect-remote-hangup)  But, nothing will do the "unknown number" before you because only your application knows that that means.  I would suggest looking at telephony options.